# How do I setup a local wordpress using Docker?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

So I decided to try Docker for my local Wordpress development.

Luckily, Docker has a [quickstart guide for that.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/)

I followed the entire process and I *think* I understood most of it. However, when I had the Docker container up and running, it made a clean installation of Wordpress instead of using the local files I had for a project. I initially thought that changing the directory to the project folder allowed it to read the files in it. Apparently, I was mistaken. I've tried searching the net for an answer and 
most of them are just tutorials into how to use Docker for WP.

So with that in mind, how do I create a Docker container (or change the Docker YAML file) that uses the local WP files I have?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

**Project structure**

```
/project
  /app
  /sql
  docker-compose.yml
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Wordpress on docker

Create the `docker-compose.yml` with the follwing

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: DoKRteST
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    # Uncomment the below code to maintain the persistancy of the data 
    # volumes:
          # - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: DoKRteST
```

`./app` folder is the actual wordpress app folder

Simply click on [image: Try in PWD] 
to run it on [Play with docker](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/)

Comment: Do I have to remove the volume outside?

Comment: What you mean outside? Just place wordpress app in app folder and run it. If you are running from scratch you just run the app without adding anything. Container will create app directly.

Comment: i think the "." that references the local folder in volume is why it wasn't syncing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just need to [mount](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) `wp-content` of the host to the container. you can look for `wp-content` in your current directory structure probably under `app/wp-content`

```
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     volumes:
        - wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
```

You can read more details [here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/wp-content-a-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-most-important-directory) and [here](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/deploy-wordpress-with-docker-compose/)